# Laravel use array of controller to echo something in view

Tags: arrays, laravel

I'm new to laravel and i'm stuck at this.
So this code gives me all my results from my table

```
$categories = new Categories();
$categories = Categories::all();
```

In my view i got a foreach loop to get all the values from the table: categories. Like so:

```
@foreach($categories as $categories)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$categories->category_id}}</td>
        <td>{{ $categories->Description }}</td>
@endforeach
```

My question is, is there a way to print all the values seperate? So i can put an anchor before them? Do i have to put it in an array?
My output must be something like this:

```
1----<a href="goGSM.php">GSM</a>
2----<a href="goGPS.php">GPS</a>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you say you want to put all of the values separate?

Comment: Now it just print all my values in one time but i want to wrap an anchor around each unique id

Comment: put an anchor around each one, its html

Comment: @foreach($categories as $categories)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$categories->category_id}}</td>
        <td>{{ $categories->Description }}</td>
@endforeach 

So lets say i want to go to the page gsm? What do i do?

Comment: @Wesley does your categories table contain a row for the link? So you could have $categories->category_url

Comment: No, should i do it?

Comment: ofc you should, thats how its done

Comment: But how? WIth the routes and stuff? I don't know how?

Comment: Can't i just put it in an array? And than in the foreach do something like get the value of the first id like so category_id[1] and that he prints gsm?

Comment: So if i do something like this
$categories = Categories::all('category_id', 'Description')->toArray();

So my question is can i do in the view something like
<td>{{ $categories[1]->category_id}}</td>

Problem is in the view i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$categories = new Categories(); // for what this line???
$categories = Categories::all();



@foreach($categories as $category)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$category->id}}</td>
        <td> <a href="{{ yourFunctionThatGeneratesURL($category) }}"> {{ $category->name }} </a> </td>
        // or as suggested in comments
        <td> <a href="{{ $category->urlToCategory }}"> {{ $category->name }} </a> </td>
        // or you can use one of the laravel's url helpers
        <td> <a href="{{ route('category.show', ['id' => $category->id ]) }}"> {{ $category->name }} </a> </td> 
        <td>{{ $category->Description }}</td>
@endforeach
```

more info about helpers you can find in [docs][1]

**EDIT**

if you have categories

```
category1
  id - 1
name - GSM

category2
  id - 2
name - GPS
```

with this code

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$category->id}}</td>
        <td><a href="go{{$category->name}}.php">{{$category->name}}</a></td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

you'll get

```
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><a href="goGSM.php">GSM</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><a href="goGPS.php">GPS</a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Good but i get an error:
Undefined variable category, what must i do? I'am really new in laravel sorry for that
['id' => $category->id ])

Comment: try `@foreach($categories as $category)`

Comment: I'am using your last solution with the url helpers
<td> <a href="{{ route('category.show', ['id' => $category->id ]) }}"> {{ $categories->name }} </a> </td>
But get the error:Undefined property:

Comment: It's my fault, you should use `$category` variable instead of `$categories` inside your foreach loop

Comment: <td>{{ $category->category_id}}</td>
            <td><a href="{{ route('eindwerk.index', ['id' => $category->id ]) }}">{{ $category->name }}</a> </td>
            <td>{{ $category->Description}}</td>

I still get no links/anchors?

Comment: what is `route('eindwerk.index', ['id' => $category->id ])` function returns?

Comment: it returns nothing... Just a list of my table with product_id and description. But no links

Comment: Do you register route with 'eindwerk.index' name? try set url manualy with [url()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-url) function

Comment: Yes the route is registered. What must i do?

Comment: try set url manualy with [url()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-url) function

Comment: I did this: 
<td><a href="{{ URL('eindwerk.index', ['id' => $category->id ]) }}"></a></td>

Still no anchors

Comment: Seems you miss anchor's title `<a href="{{ URL('eindwerk.index', ['id' => $category->id ]) }}">SOME_TEXT</a>`

Comment: And this? ['id' => $category->id ])

Don't it have to be category_id? or something?

Comment: does your route expects any parameters? perform in console `php artisan route:list`

Comment: Ok i see links now, but if i have 5 different's id like(gsm, gps, ...) i want them all to have a different link, now it all has the same link ...

Comment: without foreach then?

Comment: What do you mean with: nameOrAnyPropertyThatContainsYourId?

Comment: how do you generate your url for particular category?

Comment: I don't get it? Can you give me an example please?
I'm really sorry for my many questions

Comment: I do get it. But in laravel I do it with routes. So this will be the last question. My views are in a map called site. So my link must search into this map.
If I want to link i do it like so: site.index or site.webshop. So can you please edit it one more time? A big thank you from a laravel newbie.

Comment: I really don't understand your question. however you can't get link's to view in laravel directly. You should do it through controllers or routes. Are you familiar with MVC pattern?

Answer (score 0):

A big thank you to everyone who helped me!
This is the correct solution if you were wondering.

```
<td><a href="shop{{$category->Description}}">{{$category->Description}}</a></td>
```